# How can I speed up multi-row inserts to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am inserting about 400 rows into a table at a time (SQL Server 2008). I have tried UNION ALL, but that slowed things down considerably. I settled on the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (a, b,...),(c, d,...),...(x,y,...);
```

When I make this query through ODBC it takes roughly 400ms (I use C++ and time the single call to sqlExecDirect going to odbc32.dll). However, when I run the query inside MS SQL Server Management Studio wrapped by Getdate():

```
SELECT Getdate()
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT Getdate()
```

it takes ~10ms. For comparison, on the same machine, the same query in MySQL takes roughly 20ms.

1. Is SELECT Getdata() a reliable way to time a transaction?
2. Why is MS SQL Server Management Studio so much faster?
3. What can I do to improve the performance? Any alternatives to ODBC? Direct connect to SQL server?

Comment: The reason why SSMS query looked that fast is because I was sending the exact same query multiple times. Just changing one letter in the original query, runs 'SQL Server parse and compile' again, and the execution speed goes down to the speed very close to the ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

The first connection usually takes a while to set up.  This can explain an initial delay: in SSMS, the connection will already be in place when you start the query.  Try to do the insert twice from the same C++ program and see if that makes a difference.

Also: what ODBC driver are you using?  For ODBC, consider the native driver:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myServerAddress;
    Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Instead of ODBC, You could also use ADO through COM.  That's quite easy to do with a generated wrapper.  Then you can connect using OLE DB:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;
    Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Changing the driver to SQL Server Native Client 10.0 didn't affect performance.It seems that all of the time is spent in "SQL Server parse and compile time", which I assume is an operation that happens on the server. I am not sure what SQL server is doing, but taking 400ms to parse and compile 40kb of text seems way to long.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are benchmarking, you are not capturing compile time. Do this:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
INSERT INTO ...
```